# PHP Laravel pass parameters as post data in redirect

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

After the registration was successful I wanted to pass all the data to a login route as POST. How do you do this in laravel 4?

I know I can just authenticate the user after registration but the login page has other parameters and more required authentication process.

So I wish to push the username and password entered in the registration process into the login process so it can go through with the other processes inside the login route. (ex. Token generation which requires post data of app_id and app_secret)

Comment: You can use session for that

Comment: But this is an API. communications between mobile and api server. can't persist sessions. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If it's API call sent the authorization token in header

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Events do to that:

Register your event in `filters.php` or create an `events.php` and add it to `composer.json`:

```
Event::listen('user.registered', function($data)
{
    var_dump($data['app_id']);
    var_dump($data['app_secret']);
    var_dump($data['user']);
});
```

And fire it in your `register()` method:

```
public function register()
{
    /// register your user:

    $user = new User;

    ...

    $user->save();

    /// fire the event:

    Event::fire('user.registered', array(
                                        'app_id' => 'API', 
                                        'app_secret' => 'WHATEVER', 
                                        'user' => $user
                            ));

    /// Redirect the user to where it should go next:

    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not move alot of that extra logic into the User model.  Then you can call `$user->crazySecureLogin();` after logging in and after registering.  That way you stay DRY, and it could possibly clean up your login controller method too.  And to top it off, you don't have to worry about sending a post request as a response.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Redirect::to('routename')->withInput();
```

or

```
return Redirect::to('routename')->with('email', $emailvalue)->with('password', $passwordValue)
```

etc

Comment: Above is stored in the session and not as post.

Answer (score 0):

1. add namespace on top of your class

   ```
   use Redirect;
   ```
2. add this code to your redirect stage.

   ```
   return Redirect::route('route_name',['username' => $request->username, 
                                        'password' => $request->password]);
   ```

Comment: I think this is supposed to be `Redirector`, no?